# need to edit pod to allow communication with other pod without changing the netpol

Tags: kubernetes

I'm preparing for CKAD and found a question somewhere, I'm not sure how to approach :

you rolled out a new pod (pod A) you requested to **edit pod (A)** to allow ingress requests only from pod B and C. Similarly, A is allowed to send requests(Egress) only to B and C.

NOTE:

There are a few network policies already existing in the k8s cluster.
However, you're NOT allowed to create/update/delete a new/existing netpol.

Note - I know that we can create Network Policy and use pod A as Pod Selector. However, this question demands a different approach. Cant create new NetPol or update existing ones.
I'm thinking that we should change the labels of pod (A) so it will match the one or more policies that allow pod (A) to exchange traffic with only pod B & C, but not sure if it's the correct approach.

Comment: having recently done this exam as well: you're on the right way. this question aims to test your ability to read and understand netpolicies, and then select the correct one by labelling the pod accordingly

Answer (score 1):

As per your question - network policies are already there, so you only need to implement those.
How can you implement it in pod?
Ans - just check the selector in network policies, for example it is a podSelector with app=abc then add these labels in the pod where you want your network policies to get implemented.

Hope I have answered your question, if any further details needed then let me know.